# file_put_contents access denied on several AJAX requests (but synchronized)?

Tags: php, ajax

I am making some consecutives(recrusive) ajax request to a php file that writes request parameter to a file:

```
make_ajax(s)
{
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
 {
  if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
  {
   if(s>0)
   make_ajax(s-1)
  }
 };
xhr.open('POST','write.php?s='+s+'&string=somelongstring',true);//url + async/sync
...
xhr.send(null);
}
make_ajax(15);//start request
```

write.php:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt',$_GET['s']);
```

It seems that the server returns to the ajax request, before it closes the *text.txt* file, so the next ajax requests that is send by the recrusive get an Access Denided error because seems that the file is still open by the previrios ajax request (event it has returned)? I tested this script even with async=false but I got the same error? How I can avoid that php scripts returns before it closes the file?

**NOTE:** I am not using session, I just send data to server for saving in a file.

**NOTE2**: Here I made a simple example, in realty I am using this method for uploading file by chunks with ajax and the mozSlice method. Full code:

```
            function uploadFileXhr(o,start_byte)
            {

                var total=o.size;
                var chunk;

                var peice=1024 * 1024;//bytes to upload at once

                var end_byte=start_byte+peice;
                var peice_count=end_byte/peice;
                $('#debug').html(peice_count);
                var is_last=(total-end_byte<=0)?1:0;
                chunk=o.mozSlice(start_byte, end_byte);

                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();//prepare xhr for upload

                xhr.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
                    {
                        if(is_last==0)
                        {
                            uploadFileXhr(o,end_byte);
                        }
                    }
                };

                xhr.open('POST','upload.php',true);//url + async/sync
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');//header
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');//type for upload
                xhr.send(chunk);//send request of file 
            }
uploadFileXhr(file_input,0);//start recrusive call
```

upload.php:

```
$flag =($_GET['start']==0) ? 0:FILE_APPEND;
file_put_contents($remotePath.$add.$file_name, file_get_contents('php://input'),$flag);
```

**NOTE3**: OK actually founded a workaround to avoid that error, in upload.php script:

```
        $flag =($_GET['start']==0) ? 0:FILE_APPEND;
        $file_part=file_get_contents('php://input');
        while(@file_put_contents($remotePath.$add.$file_name, $file_part,$flag)===FALSE)
        {
            usleep(50);
        }
```

But still I can't explain why i get access denided error in the first case, so waiting for comments!

Comment: Where exactly are you getting an "access denied" error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: `file_put_contents()` is blocking. The script won't finish until the file is closed.

Comment: this is the error:Warning: fopen(js/test.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www (I try with standard fopen and with file_put_contents, same problem)

Comment: So if I have 15 ajax request, it gives this error on 4-5 of the ajax requests. The rest of request goes successfully as firebug reports

Comment: @albanx, if you have 15 concurrent requests, it's quite likely that the file is locked by one of the previous requests.

Comment: Yes but every request is made when the previrious request finish. Note in the readyStateChange function

Comment: You say this is `syncronized`, but actually your code is async - it should be `xhr.open(...,...,false);` for synchronous (blocking) requests...

Comment: @DaveRandom syncronized I mean that the next ajax request is done when the prev request return: note the readystatechange function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does any content at all appear in the target file(test.txt)? I.e. does it fail *after* the first request is made or does it fail right away? The error suggests that the server cannot write to the file. This could be either because some other process is using the file or because the web server doesn't have write permissions to the file. Just to eliminate the obvious, make sure that your web server is actually allowed to write to the file.

Comment: Yes, the server can't read the file for some seconds, I founded a solution(see NOTE3) but, I still do not know why that happens on localhost testing with wamp.